# roscore, roswtf commands not found

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been following the instructions to install ROS diamondback in anticipation of running ROS on NXT, but neither of these commands will work.  I assume that this is probably a PATH problem, but I am not sure where the variable is or what path I should add to it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12726/roscore,-roswtf-commands-not-found/) by [Chuck Untulis](https://answers.ros.org/users/1683/chuck-untulis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2012-01-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This very likely is caused by not following the installation instructions correctly. Are you sure you properly added the setup script in your .bashrc file as described [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/Installation/Ubuntu) under 'environment setup'?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Stefan,

Thank you very much.  That was it.  Now roscore is running.

Chuck

---

Originally posted by [Chuck Untulis](https://answers.ros.org/users/1683/chuck-untulis/) with karma: 21 on 2012-01-23

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1